# Is it possible to add spring MVC (with embedded Jetty) to a spring integration component

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I have examples of both working individually, now trying to merge so that I have both capabilities / entry points.

Not surpised it is confused about the application contexts to load.

I want to know if this is even possible and if so any examples?

I know it is doable with spring boot however not wanting to move to that just yet.

I am attempting the impossible?

Answer (score 0):

"Spring MVC (with embedded Jetty)" usually means an HTTP endpoint running in its own JVM (I suppose you have a main method that starts Jetty). Once you have that started, you can integrate it as any other HTTP endpoint in Spring Integration.

If you want them both to run in the same JVM, that probably means you don't want to make use of HTTP as you can invoke methods directly on your `@Controller`s or `@Service`s.

Or perhaps I'm missing something here... ?

Comment: Hi Costi, yes starting jetty in main as "normal" in the mvc compononent, and you are correct, I only want to invoke (simple) methods on the @Controller. The other integration component creates JMS messages and receives responses async via MessageListener. Question is can I combine these two components in the same jvm?

Comment: I can't see why you need an actual `@Controller` (not to mention why you need an embedded Jetty). Why aren't those methods marked as `@ServiceActivator`s (or whatever makes sense) rather than `@RequestMapping`s ?

Comment: I would like the entry point accessible via curl or browser(url) thus the @Controller, and therefore also embedd Jetty to make this possible without need to host on web container. I haven't used ServiceActivitor (quite new to spring), but my understanding is it requires a channel. In my case requests will be sent to the app from an external script and this http / curl route.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for Spring Boot. Version 1.1.6 was just released. I'm currently also migrating an "old" SI application to be based upon Spring Boot. I suggest you give http://start.spring.io a try. Migration should not be too difficult.

Comment: Yes it is tempting and it would be great to know if spring boot is really "prod ready" or not, I guess I will move to it at some point but not just yet. Experience has taught me to never move to version 1.X of anything if you can't afford the risk.

Comment: Well we are currently preparing everything to move this into production at the moment. At the moment I'd say yes since all the components behind boot are mature and more or less rock solid. I had the biggest headaches with all the automatics that are happening in the back, like enabling Security but then feeling left alone configuring it properly.